# String capitalization not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capitalization

What can be the reason of string capitalization not working?

A database column:

```
t.string   "name",       limit: 255
```

Some example:

```
flower_name = Flower.find_by(id: 1).name #=> "chamomile©"
```

Trying to capitalize (got the same output):

```
flower_name.capitalize #=> "chamomile©"
```

Checking if it is string:

```
flower_name.is_a?(String) #=> true
```

Comment: What do `flower_name.chars` and `flower_name.codepoints` return?

Comment: Is it possible that someone overrode the `capitalize` method?

Comment: Do a simple test in the console: flower_name = "John Do", the try capitalize again. If it doesn't work, the method might be overwritten. You could remove as many gems as you can an try it again to see if elimination would fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) works with ASCII characters only. Is there any chance your string contains non-ascii letters?

Try

```
flower_name.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @Zelenka your question doesn't include any non-ASCII characters. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've changed an output word for the security reason. But you're right, I will edit my question to add a non-ASCII character for future readers. Thank you, Stefan!

Comment: @Zelenka `capitalize` only affects the first character, i.e. `"chamomile©".capitalize` returns `"Chamomile©"`, just as expected ...

Comment: Stefan, would you help me to provide a good example? I have no idea why ```.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s``` helped in my case

Comment: @Zelenka does you actual string start with an ASCII character?

Comment: It starts with a cyrillic letter

Answer (score 2):

[`mb_chars`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars) method may help you if you are using **Rails >= 3**.

```
 'æ-ý'.mb_chars.upcase

 => "Æ-Ý"
```

If you're **not using Rails**, you can:

- use directly [active_support](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/4.2.5.1) gem:

  `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'`
- try [unicode](https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode) gem.

I hope you will find an answer in this similar question: [Special character uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211780/special-character-uppercase/30238865#30238865)